# Active tab issue im trying to isolate

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-visualization

I am working with adding google charts to a no-code site, and the code im working with is inside a function that is called when the page is loaded. The problem is this code doesn't work if I have the window its in open, but if im in another tab while the page is loading it works. Im wondering if pages load differently (on chrome at least) when they are not the active tab? Not really looking for a solution so much as high level insight as to what could be happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
</script>

//This function is called when the element becomes visible on the page
function(instance, context) {
    var divPie = $('<div id="curve_chart"></div>');
    instance.canvas.append(divPie);

    drawPie();

    function drawPie() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
        ['2007',  1030,      540]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance'
      };

      var chart = new 
      google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by _this code doesn't work_? are there any errors in the browser's console (press F12 on most)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean the chart appears if the tab its in is not active and then I view the tab whereas if I just refresh the page no chart appears. The console is throwing the error "Element Chart A - The plugin Google Charts (testing) / element Chart threw the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the console helped me solve the issue, I will start using that more. It was just a matter of making sure the library was loaded prior to displaying the element. Switching tabs was just mimicking that waiting till the library is loaded behavior.